# Full circle gauge in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, gauge

I have a problem when I try to include a full circle Gauge/Gage in Ionic, because the gauge never appears.

Has anyone ever succeeded to include a complete circle Gauge in ionic like that:

[image]

I found a GitHub of what can be perfect (from a design point of view):

https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar

So, I just added that

```
<script>
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RoundProgressModule} from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

@NgModule({
imports: [RoundProgressModule]
})
export class YourModule {};
</script>
```

in my index.html after run npm install `angular-svg-round-progressbar --save` in the console.
Then I added the round `progress tag` in one of my templates, but anything appears.

Comment: May we see what you have tried? That is probably the best place for people to start helping you.

Comment: Ok so, how can I show you my project ?

Comment: Paste the necessary parts of your code into your question, select them in turn, and hit the code button. Show us the smallest possible piece(s) of code that replicate the problem you are having. For HTML/CSS/JS problems, consider using JS Fiddle. Read the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) here too.

Comment: I just added that `<script>
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RoundProgressModule} from 'angular-svg-round-progressbar';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RoundProgressModule]
})
export class YourModule {};
</script>` in my index.html after run `npm install angular-svg-round-progressbar --save` in the console. Then I added the round progress tag in one of my templates.

Comment: That looks like it should be formatted using block formatting. Did you try pasting it in and using the "code" button, as I suggested? It looks like `{}` in the editor toolbar.

Comment: [in response to deleted comment] Yes, if that's what your code looks like, though most people use carriage returns to avoid the need to scroll.

Comment: No problem. Can you replicate the issue in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and edit the link into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read through the [issues in github](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar/issues/) of that library, you will find one that says the lib does not work in angular 2. See this https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar/issues/65

There are some workarounds, like using another library, this one https://github.com/subarroca/ng2-kw-gauge

Comment: Indeed I read it...So I will give up with this library for the moment. I explored the ng2-kw-gauge github and I tried to include it in an app without succes and already without error in the console... But I seen people have problems (https://github.com/subarroca/ng2-kw-gauge/issues/1)So, did I have to create another question for this particular library ?

Comment: Ok. Yes, make another question!